# Web3Auth method to enter email Id and get the value of wallet address as return value

Tags: web3js, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, react, web3auth

Is there any web3Auth method which takes email id as input and returns a wallet address as output ? The wallet address returned should be real . By real I mean , if the user logs in with the emailId we get the same address that was our output from the method .

Tried looking for something in the documentation , it is so vast and I have very less time . Will be grateful if I get any sort of help from here. Reference : https://web3auth.io/

Answer (score 1):

Once you are logged in with your social login you will get your `web3AuthProvider`. Then you can instantiate a classic `ethers.web3.provider` like this and get the signer and the associated wallet address

```
const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3AuthProvider!);

const signer = web3Provider.getSigner();

const address = await signer.getAddress();
const balance = (await signer.getBalance()).toString();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @donoso.eth , thanks for answering . But this is not the answer that I expected . I have a DApp , where I want to assign a role to a user of the application . This assigning thing will be done by Admin . I want to create a form like UI where I will enter email address of a person say donoso@gmail.com and assign him the role I want . I've implemented this functionality by taking wallet address as input but to make it more web2 like , I want that email input functionality , such that my dapp is able to calculate what address will be generated for donoso@gmail.com

Comment: `want that email input functionality , such that my dapp is able to calculate what address will be generated for donoso@gmail.com` This is not how blockchains work, unfortunately. Blockchains operate on addresses, not on emails, and it is not possible to know person's address by knowing his email.